# What could possibly cause a .Q.l error when loading an HDB?

Tags: kdb

[image]

not much else to say.
I applied fncol erroneusly:

```
fncol[dir;`tab;`col;{$[x~`false;0b;1b]}]; // replaced all cols with 1 value instead of a list
```

now I cannot load the hdb

col is needs to be 0b for all values.

I then deleted the col and added it back correctly but the hdb does not load anymore

When loading just the offending table

.z.ex is "in"

.z.ey is the table

.z.ey looks like this :

```
(`;+`time`pubTime` ...
```

Comment: If should have been ``fncol[dir;`tab;`col;{?[x=`false;0b;1b]}];`` or simply ``fncol[dir;`tab;`col;{not x=`false}];`` - you saved the column as an atom not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem with the structure of the .d file.

Applying the fncol with wrong arguments did not mess up the .d file.

However, the steps I took to try to fix that (basically deleting the col and adding it back with a set of default values) updated the .d file in a way that it was an empty schema rather than a list of symbols.

This was causing the issue above.

In order to fix this I had to iterate through all partitions, load .d file extract only the cols from the schema and save it back down.

This was the command I ran :

```
{x set cols get x}each hsym`$system"find -type f -name .d | grep tableName"
```

This worked for me.

The hdb wasn't loading either, but it did load after EOD (because the .d file would have been reset by the EOD procedure). Even though the load would have worked, all the partitions where .d was wrong would not be queryable.